# Do I need a premium account to play Minecraft offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to run the offline version of Minecraft (which I'm told doesn't need a premium account?) but the "play offline" button is greyed out, with the text underneath it reading "not downloaded".

Do you need a premium account to play offline?

Note: I've also tried using the `assets.minecraft.net/1.8/minecraft.jar` but I encounter this (fatal) error: `java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jni/libjinput.so: undefined symbol: EVIOCGUSAGE`

I'm also a bit worried that what I'm doing might not be allowed - is the minecraft.jar file from assets.minecraft.net legal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Yes, you do need a premium account to play Minecraft offline.

The first time it is run the client requires you to log in with a premium account to download the necessary files from minecraft.net.

See the [FAQ for Minecraft](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/329518-what-happens-after-i-pay-).

Comment: The link seems broken... It says: `Last Updated: Liquid error: undefined method 'in_time_zone' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score -4):

You can, if you have a account on minecraft.net. You can do this from the homepage. Look for the download button, (below a player with the default skin) and press that to download minecraft. After launching minecraft, you will see a login page, so enter your username and password. It will say "user not premium" and "play offline", therefore you can't get Minecraft player skins offline.

Comment: nope, without an account that minecraft.exe will not download the required game data