# Does playing Minecraft on a LAN require all players to have an account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son wants to have a Minecraft LAN birthday party, but some friends don't have an account.  If I host a private LAN server can we just setup accounts for them?  Or does everyone need to have a paid-off account?

From this:  [Do I need a premium account to play Minecraft offline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49110/do-i-need-a-premium-account-to-play-minecraft-offline)  I see you need one account to get the server running but what about the other players?

Comment: Yes, Minecraft also requires you to log in at least once (to build the account information locally) in order to play offline. And each player must have their own unique account. It's rather irritating but mojang wouldn't make any money otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only legal option is to buy an account for every child attending your son's birthday. I hope he has a great party, a minecraft LAN party is a great idea!

Comment: May I have a link to the current moderator policies?

Comment: For information about moderators, please view [this help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) sub-section. The [main help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) may also be of use, and also please bear in mind that anyone with enough reputation can edit questions and answers, not just moderators.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, both links were very informative.

Comment: Also FYI, there are very few moderators here.  The vast majority of us are just regular users like yourself.  We just have an interest in keeping the site clean.

Comment: This is understandable.  Since this is fairly off topic the only thing im going to say is that I feel I've been judged/edited "too" harshly on some comments without justification but I can only chalk that up to my personal opinion.

Comment: @slow_excellence I'm glad to explain my actions. Your first answer condoned piracy, which is patently disallowed. Your second answer alluded to the first answer, which is no better to be honest. While I was editing your answer, fixing things up, I removed irrelevant extra text as well (which I see you've added back; remember that this is a Q&A site and content is important, but greetings and opinions are not). Your comment was flagged as offensive (not by me), and comments are cheap so we tend to err on the side of deletion.